# calling javascript pixel wise

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have two javascript files which are used for menus.
both of the javascripts will work differently.
one for the tabs and computers and one for the mobiles.
at a time only one working properly.
now the problems is if device width is less then 768px then mobile.js will work
and if it is more then 768px desktop.js will work.
I really don't know how to do that.
any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://yepnopejs.com/ you can use it to conditionally include javascript.  It's possible to hand roll this as well.